# Date picker calendar gets buried under the Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net, javascript, datepicker

I downloaded a Datepicker from the net and modified it a little bit according to my need. It works fine, but I have a small problem.

The calendar dropdown gets buried under the DropDown list that is just below the date picker.

[Click For Image Here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?13e2730688.jpg)

Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an IE Bug (the geniuses developing IE6 decided to use windows controls).  You'll need to place an iframe on top of the dropdown element, and the calendar popup on top of that...most pickers like [jQuery UI for example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), do this.

Comment: jQuery UI comes with bgiframe.js that handle IE bug like this.

Comment: The sample looks good.. But unfortunately as I'm racing with time, and since JQuery is completely new to me... I was unable to go with this, for this app.. I will surely learn jquery and will try to use it in my next app...

Answer (score 0):

Yep... IE bug.  This is fixed in IE7+ I believe?

What I usually do is just add a little javascript to the datepicker that hides the dropdowns.  Usually there is already some existing event or function to show/hide the calendar; just piggyback on top of that.